# How to efficiently calculate line position with a strokewidth

Tags: position, javafx, stroke

I'm using JavaFX to test some graph properties. But I'm searching to calculate the right position of a line according to its stroke width.
If you draw a line with a strokeWidth with JavaFX, you create a line wrapped by the defined width.

For absolute positioning, it becomes difficult to position your line.
So I would like to define an algorithm to position the line outer of the coordinates or inner of the coordinates. (I'm not talking about strokeType property)

Do someone know an algorithm to do it, orientation-independant ?
I used `myPath.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.BUTT);`to avoid end-point width.

But now I need to compute a gap to move my line outer of the coordinates, or inner of the coordinates..

Answer (score 0):

I did a try with a thin line (l1) and a bolder line (l2) :
But my code is orientation-dependant, my calculation method (adding a gap) only works for a outer left line...

```
    Line l1 = new Line();
    l1.setStartX(400);
    l1.setStartY(50);
    l1.setEndX(400);
    l1.setEndY(400);

    double sWidth1 = 1;
    double sWidth2 = 10;
    double ecart = sWidth2*0.5 + sWidth1;
    Line l2 = new Line();
    l2.setStartX(400+ecart);
    l2.setStartY(50);
    l2.setEndX(400+ecart);
    l2.setEndY(400);

    l2.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    l2.setStrokeWidth(10);
    l2.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.BUTT);
```